# How to match numbers with unclosed parens against closed parens using rexex (Python)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I struggle to find a good regex match for that kind of sentence:

> 1) Remove the modern cement (20) render to the front of all three
>   properties 2) Inspect the sole plate and studs at front of all three
>   properties, repair where possible, and replace where rotten 3) Apply
>   sawn lath and lime render 4) Finish with limewash including pigment to
>   as closely match existing colour as possible (30)

The thing is to match `1)`, `2)`, `3)`, `4)` but NOT `(20)` nor `(30)`.

My try:
`((?!\([0-9]+\))\s*\d+\s*\))`
fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using capturing groups `\(\d+\)|(\d+\))` https://regex101.com/r/an635C/1 Or if it should only work for a single digit `(?<!\d)\d\)`

Comment: Replacing group 1: `re.sub("\(\d+\)|(\d+\))", ".", s, flags=re.I)` - just need to use `group(1)`.

Comment: Try this: `(?<![(]|\d)(\d+[)]{1})` - https://regex101.com/r/VMY6p5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![\d(])\d+\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypnaVh/1)

**Details**

- `(?<![\d(])` - no digit or `(` immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Here is a [Python code snippet](https://ideone.com/xkPudO) that wraps the matches with `{{` and `}}` (just for the demo purpose):

```
import re
text = "1) Remove the modern cement (20) render to the front of all three properties 2) Inspect the sole plate and studs at front of all three properties, repair where possible, and replace where rotten 3) Apply sawn lath and lime render 4) Finish with limewash including pigment to as closely match existing colour as possible (30)"
print( re.sub( r'(?<![\d(])\d+\)', r'{{\g<0>}}', text) )
```

Output:

`{{1)}} Remove the modern cement (20) render to the front of all three properties {{2)}} Inspect the sole plate and studs at front of all three properties, repair where possible, and replace where rotten {{3)}} Apply sawn lath and lime render {{4)}} Finish with limewash including pigment to as closely match existing colour as possible (30)`